# Who get Access to the Database in MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, database, mvvm

After reading many articles about this i'm still not really sure what's the best solution could look like

Some telling me the `ViewModel` and the `Model` should get access to Database other are telling me only the `Model` should get access.

Further more does this also really depends on the way i connect to my database?
if i use a Repository should really both get access to it 
and
what if i want to use a EF should now only the "Model" are able to perform Database interactions?

Or does anybody know's a general rule about who should when are able to get access to the Database?

Comment: Logins/Users get access to the database, not parts of your code. What I guess you are actually asking is, what identities should the tiers of my MVVM application run with and, do those identites need access to the database? Do you want to audit user activity?

Comment: The general rule is, access should be limited to minimum level necessary to achieve your requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should devide your application in Layers

- UI layer - Responsible for the graphic part of your application containing your Views and ViewModels.
- BusinessLayer - This is the layer your UI layer speaks with. Containing all logic and and it functions as gateway to your database. This contains your model and domain model.
- Database layer - This layer is responsible for all communication to your database, generally providing generic methods for your Business layer to access and persist your data.

You should keep a clear seggregation between your UI and data.

There are offcourse many variations on this setup.

Comment: Segregation would be the main point here. The 'division' is very fluent and often there's no clear line where one layer should end and other begin, or even if we need one of the layers at all (DAL? The fully fledged Business Layer? Depends on the project).

Comment: Indeed this depends on the project. But this is a basic layout that can suit many needs.

Comment: in [THIS](http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/05/mvvm.html#.UUq4GBxLNWg) article he mention that the Model == BL and the BL is the only on how should get access to the DAL

Comment: @WiiMaxx yes some developers like to put their BL in their models, but that is not the only way to do it. Other developers prefer to keep their models clean - only properties and no logic, kind of like a Data Transfer Object. These developers would put their logic in the ViewModel or in another layer and the ViewModel calls that layer to perform BL. Bottom line - don't put your logic in the view lol